# How to fix Spyder breaks at line one during debugging without any breakpoint

Tags: spyder

My issue is my code during debugging always stops at line 1.  For example this is my code:

```
import gc
import os
import pandas as pd
import shutil
from pandas      import DataFrame
from pathlib     import Path
from datetime    import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict
```

It simply behaves as if there is a breakpoint in line 1.  Before there were comments on the first few lines and Spyder breaks in the middle of the comments.  I have to press "Continue" for it to proceed.

Now this does not happen in my other python files so I really don't have the slightest clue how to fix this unless I incrementally write the program and run it.

Anyone face such issue?

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint in this file? If not, that's the normal behavior. In other words, if we detect there's a breakpoint in the file you're trying to debug, we automatically run `Continue` on it. If not, we simply start a debugging session. Breakpoints could be present in other files, but it's not easy for us to detect them. So if we'd run `Continue` and there are no breakpoints, the debugging session would finish.

Comment: Maybe it not clear.  I am trying to debug the program and the breakpoint is elsewhere.  But whenever I run via (Debug File) it stops at Line 1.  I have to press (Continue Execution until next breakpoint) before it proceeds normally.   Thank you for your reply btw.

Comment: As I said, if your breakpoint is elsewhere, what you're seeing is the expected behavior in our debugger: first you need to start a debugging session and then manually continue to your breakpoint.

Comment: oh really.. i see got it.  Is there a way to disable this behavior?  I feel it is unnecessary.  If not, no worries.

Comment: No, there isn't, sorry.

Comment: oh well.  Anyway, thank you for your reply. cheers!

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

in the setting -->iPython console -> debugger, you will see an option "stop debugging on first line of file without breakpoints"

Answer (score 0):

go to debug option in top menu and click clear breakpoints in all files

-->debug-->clear breakpoints in all files